# Is it logical to invoke other intent from the custom intent in an Alexa app

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My interaction has to be executed in two steps. in first step. Alexa will get some information to the user. On the basis of published information, Alexa will ask to take another action from the user's answer (Which is yes/no).

So is it possible to invoke one intent and on the basis of previous intent's reply through reprompt, i would be able to call another intent of alexa app.

if so, then how can i do that through akexa node js SDK v2.

**Use Case:**
My app is connecting with third party API which needs alexa to use Account Linking. Scenario is, when my account is linked and i have valid access token. Here's how conversation will go:

> User: Alexa, ask "a" to get me overdue invoices.
>   Alexa: You have "x" number of invoices. Do you want to send payment reminders?
>   User: Yes.
>   Alexa: Your request to send reminders has been registered. Anything else I can help?
>   User: No Thanks.

So for this, I have to communicate with an external API two times. One, while getting overdue invoices, and two, while sending reminders.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use a single intent and perhaps slots to determine how to proceed with fulfilling that intent. I suggest making intents only for completely separate actions that the user will trigger by themselves. And for intents that are too similar or depend on each other, restructure those into one intent and use slots. Of course it depends on your use case, so if you insist, then maybe add more specific example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: My app is connecting with third party API which needs alexa to use Account Linking.  Scenario is, when my account is linked and i have valid access token. Here's how conversation will go. 

User: Alexa, ask "a" to get me overdue invoices.
Alexa: You have "x" number of invoices. Do you want to send payment reminders.
User: Yes.
Alexa: your request to send reminders has been registered. Anything else i can help?
User: No Thanks.
So for this, i have to communicate with external API two times. one, while getting overdue invoices. and while sending reminders. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I'm guessing you have `invoices` as one intent, then `reminders` as another intent. If `reminders` is only ever used immediately after `invoices`, then I'd make them a single intent. But if you want users to create reminders at any point, or if you have multiple intents that could flow into the `reminders` intent, then separate intents can work.

Check out:
[**How to Pass a new Intent**](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#pass-a-new-intent)

> Each of the Dialog directives includes an `updatedIntent` property that can take an Intent object. Use this to:
>
> - **Trigger a dialog on a completely different intent.** For example, after completing the dialog for a BookFlight intent, you could return `Dialog.Delegate` with `updatedIntent` set to `BookRentalCar` to start new dialog.
>
> ...
>   When you use `updatedIntent` to change to a different intent, the directive acts against the new intent instead of the original:
>
> ...
>   When you use `updatedIntent` to set or change data on the original intent, make sure that the intent name and full set of slots matches the intent sent to your skill.

So to use your example, this is what you would do:

1. **User: *Alexa, ask SkillName to get me overdue invoices.***

   - Trigger `invoices` intent.
   - Make API call, get # invoices.
   - Return `Dialog.Delegate` or `Dialog.ElicitSlot` or `Dialog.ConfirmIntent` with `updatedIntent` set to `reminders` intent. (include any and all slots, must be a full intent object)
   - Set the outputSpeech to "You have X number of invoices. Do you want to send payment reminders?"
2. **Alexa: *You have X number of invoices. Do you want to send payment reminders?***
3. **User: *Yes.***

   - Depending on which Dialog Directive you've chosen to use, it will return the user's answer differently. Either filling a slot you've prepared, or in a `confirmationStatus`, or `AMAZON.YesIntent`.
   - Check for the correct one of those, and make your reminders API call if confirmed.
   - Return fulfilled intent with output message:
4. **Alexa: *Your request to send reminders has been registered. Anything else I can help?***

Comment: I am trying to digest it and apply your suggestions. Yeah, you are right. Since i have different intent for reminders . "**Alexa, ask app to send overdue reminders.**". that's why i have to keep separate intent. Dialog seems to me quite close to what I am looking for.